# Visualize info in just custom post_type in theme

Tags: custom-post-types, php, theme-development, localhost

So in a local wordpress I created a plugin that will make a row with its custom post type called book (it is saving successfully in the db)... and now I want to display a special template for it in the index of my theme, but after I use this code nothing shows:

```
<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'book', 'category_name' => 'book', 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'paged' => $paged ) );
////
if($loop->have_posts()):
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
   <div class="ptitle">
                    <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
                </div>
  <h3> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
  <small>Posted on:<?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>, in
   <?php the_category(); ?> </small>
<p>   <?php the_content(); ?> </p>
<hr>
<?php
endwhile;
endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you doing a new `WP_Query()`? If you set up a `single-cptslug.php` file in the theme, it will already automatically be running a query for you, which you can modify with `pre_get_posts` if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loops itself is working. I guess you have trouble to output this content on some page template. There are many ways how to show output of this loop on the homepage.

1.You can create `home.php` file, put there your code and in theme settings select which page should output your custom post type.

2.You can create page template according to the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/), put there your code, create some page in wordpress admin and on the right side in editor menu choose your newly created template.